# How to use a counter value in a hypertarget name?

Tags: bookmarks

I am trying to mark places in my document automatically (for later bookmarking). I defined a counter `nops` and my marking macro should be like this:
`\newcommand{\nop}{\addtocounter{nops}{1}\hypertarget{nop\value{nops}}{}}`,
but it seems that this is not the correct way to do it, since a bookmark like 
`\bookmark[dest=nop3]{third occurrence}` always just brings me to the title page.

I assume this is a more general problem like 'how to use commands where text is expected' but I don't know enough about latex to properly classify it. Someone more knowledgeable may change the title and tags (seems I can't create any meaningful tags like 'counter value hypertarget name' or 'dynamic bookmarks' for this anyhow).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `\value{nops}`, you get the internal representation of the counter (`\c@nops`) instead of its actual value which you can get e.g. with `\arabic{nops}` as an arabic number. So your definition must be

```
\newcommand{\nop}{\addtocounter{nops}{1}\hypertarget{nop\arabic{nops}}{}}
```

to make your bookmarks work.

Comment: Thanks, it works. That was easy. So when would I use `\value`?

Comment: I found it out while preparing and thereby obsoleting my next question: http://mathematics.nsetzer.com/latex/latex_for_loop.html.