# How to use a counter in a \bookmark dest name within \BookmarkAtEnd?

Tags: macros, expansion, bookmarks

I'm trying to do something similar as in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16994/how-to-use-a-counter-value-in-a-hypertarget-name) question.

I would like to use the value of a counter in the name of a `\hypertarget` and in addition, I want to be able to refer to this name in a `\bookmark` inside a `\BookmarkAtEnd`.

Here is a MWE of what I'm trying to do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[atend]{bookmark}
\BookmarkAtEnd{\bookmark[level=0,named=LastPage]{Foos}}
\newcounter{foo}
\newcommand{\foo}{
  \refstepcounter{foo}
  \def\target{foo\arabic{foo}}
  \hypertarget{\target}{Foo: \target}
  \BookmarkAtEnd{\bookmark[level=1,dest=\target]{\target}}
}
\begin{document}
\foo

\foo
\end{document}
```

The bookmarks show up alright but the problem is they both link to the last target. As can be seen from the output of the MWE, the problem is that everything inside `\BookmarkAtEnd` is not expanded until the end of the document.

Is there a way to make sure the  calls to `\target` inside `\BookmarkAtEnd` are expanded right away?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to expand `\target` and `\arabic{foo}` when you use it to set the bookmark, otherwise `\BookmarkAtEnd` uses the last meaning of `\target` both for the text and the destination:

```
\newcounter{foo}
\newcommand{\foo}{%
  \refstepcounter{foo}%
  \begingroup
  \def\target{foo\arabic{foo}}%
  \edef\x{\endgroup
  \noexpand\hypertarget{\target}{Foo: \target}%
  \noexpand\BookmarkAtEnd{\noexpand\bookmark[level=1,dest=\target]{\target}}}\x
}
```

When you call `\foo`, first of all we step the counter and this defines an anchor. Now, in a group (it is not required, but it's better), we define the meaning of `\target` and then we proceed to set the `\hypertarget` and the `\bookmark` using the *current* value of `foo` and of `\target`. So an expanded definition is necessary and it's accomplished with the `\edef` of `\x`; when `\x` is finally expanded, the `\endgroup` will annihilate its definition.

Note that if the expansion of `\target` contains commands such as `\emph` or `\textbf`, a slightly different approach must be taken:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\foo}{%
  \refstepcounter{foo}%
  \begingroup
  \def\target{foo\arabic{foo}}%
  \protected@edef\x{\endgroup
  \noexpand\hypertarget{\target}{Foo: \target}%
  \noexpand\BookmarkAtEnd{\noexpand\bookmark[level=1,dest=\target]{\target}}}\x
}
\makeatother
```

because `\protected@edef` is safe with commands that shouldn't be "completely expanded". If you're sure that the expansion of `\target` must contain only plain ASCII characters, then `\edef` can be used (but `\protected@edef` doesn't hurt either, so the second method is generally preferable).

Comment: Thanks a lot! That solved my problem. BTW, it is not necessary to add \hypertarget within \x because its arguments seem to be expanded in time.

Comment: I just have one more question about the grouping you use: would it make any difference if I put the \endgroup after the invocation of \x instead of inside its definition?

Comment: I don't know how `\BookmarkAtEnd` works; with this technique you're sure that this command is issued *outside* that group.